# Is there any way to add the toolbar at the bottom of the new Firefox start page to the Ubuntu start page?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, 64-bit

Is there any way to add the toolbar at the bottom of the new Firefox 13 start page to the Firefox for Ubuntu start page? I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.[image: Firefox 13 Start Page] [image: Ubuntu Start Page]

Comment: Can you please add an image?

Comment: That's the Firefox's specific about:home, the second is Firefox Ubuntu's start page, two different things you can view the code of the first and add it to the second.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the bar at the bottom that you can add tools to, it is already there but is hidden by default.

If I am right in what you are asking,  in the Firefox menu go to View>Toolbars>Add-on Bar. 
It will then pop up on the bottom of the screen. If you then right click on it and select customise, you can drag the widgets on and off the bar.

I tried to take a screen shot to show you the bar active but it is white, so is too hard to see in the picture and distinguish from the rest of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

To have home snippets, the home page must be set to `about:home`, not to `about:startpage`.